# Can not access variables in $GLOBALS using laravel and slim PHP framework

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, slim

I want to access variables through $GLOBALS variable in PHP using Laravel or slim framework.

```
$FORUM = array('test');

print_r($GLOBALS["FORUM"]);
```

I don't know why using Laravel or slim framework can not get the result. It is empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry. Should be print_r

Comment: The code you've posted works fine. You're not executing it at global scope.

Comment: @meagar, you are right. It is inside the PHP frameworks. Any ideas how to get global in the PHP framework?

Comment: Yeah, add it to public/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this:

```
$FORUM = array('test');
```

To:

```
$GLOBALS["FORUM"] = array('test);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: From the PHP manual example `echo '$foo in global scope: ' . $GLOBALS["foo"] . "\n";` . $GLOBALS["foo"]  does not need to be assigned  value.

Comment: You can use $FORUM in the global scope by using the global keyword, eg: "global $FORUM;"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$GLOBALS["FORUM"] = array('test');


dd($GLOBALS["FORUM"]);
```

By the way: You can't use echo on an array. Use var_dump() instead.

Comment: From the PHP manual example `echo '$foo in global scope: ' . $GLOBALS["foo"] . "\n";` . $GLOBALS["foo"]  does not need to be assigned  value.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

php > echo '$foo in global scope: ' . $GLOBALS["foo"] . "\n";
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: foo in php shell code on line 1